# Can I combine the results from multiple columns into a single column without UNION?

Tags: mysql, union

I have a table with several columns which I want to `SELECT`:

```
SELECT his_name , her_name, other_name FROM foo;
```

Bu, I instead I want to combine the results all into a single column.
As an example, I can do this with `UNION ALL` as

```
SELECT her_name AS name FROM foo
UNION ALL
SELECT his_name AS name FROM foo
UNION ALL
SELECT other_name AS name FROM foo
```

Is there more elegant way to do this operation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is unclear to me what is a "more elegant way".

Oracle you can use the [following statement](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/de49c/1) to make columns to rows

```
select all_name
from foo
unpivot (all_name for col_name in (
  his_name, 
  her_name,
  other_name));
```

This is the [syntax diagram](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html) of the select statement

```
SELECT
    [ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
      [HIGH_PRIORITY]
      [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
      [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
      [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
    select_expr [, select_expr ...]
    [FROM table_references
      [PARTITION partition_list]
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
    [HAVING where_condition]
    [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ...]
    [LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
    [PROCEDURE procedure_name(argument_list)]
    [INTO OUTFILE 'file_name'
        [CHARACTER SET charset_name]
        export_options
      | INTO DUMPFILE 'file_name'
      | INTO var_name [, var_name]]
    [FOR UPDATE | LOCK IN SHARE MODE]]
```

Neither the `WHERE`,`GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, `LIMIT`, `SELECT`, `INTO`, `FOR UPDATE` nor the `LOCK IN SHARE MODE` clause can increase the number of rows defined by the `FROM` clause.
So if `table_references` equals `foo` the  query cannot contains more rows than the table `foo`.
So MySQL does not have such an "elegant" way to unpivot a table.

A way to do such unpivoting without the use of UNION can be done buy using a join. We want to create 3 rows for each row of the `foo` table, so we create an auxiliary table containing three rows 
and (cross) join it to the `foo` table. Now we have three rows in our query for each row in the base table `foo`. Each query row can be filled by the appropriate data. Instead the ELT function one can use IF or CASE.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a685/4)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table foo (
  his_name varchar(10),
  her_name varchar(10), 
  other_name varchar(10));

insert into foo(his_name,her_name,other_name) values ('one','two','three');
insert into foo(his_name,her_name,other_name) values ('four','five','six');

create  table aux(line int);
insert into aux(line) values(1);
insert into aux(line) values(2);
insert into aux(line) values(3);
```

**Pivot Query**:

```
select elt(aux.line,foo.his_name,foo.her_name,foo.other_name) all_name
from foo  cross join  aux
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a685/4/0)**:

```
| all_name |
|----------|
|      one |
|     four |
|      two |
|     five |
|    three |
|      six |
```

Of course there are different ways to create a table containing the three rows  with values 1,2,3:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8637d/7)

**Using an auxiliary table**:

```
create  table aux(line int);
insert into aux(line) values(1);
insert into aux(line) values(2);
insert into aux(line) values(3);
```

**Using an auxiliary table**:

```
select line
from aux
```

**using a constant expression**:

```
select 1 line 
union all 
select 2 
union all 
select 3
```

**counting row numbers**:
I found it [here](http://www.fseitz.de/blog/index.php?/archives/44-ROWNUM-unter-MySQL.html)

```
SELECT
 @rownum := @rownum + 1 line
 FROM
(SELECT @rownum := 0) r, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS t
where @rownum<3
```

**using one of the dictionary views**:

```
SELECT
 ordinal_position  line
 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS t
where table_catalog='def'
and table_schema='information_schema'
and table_name='COLUMNS'
and ordinal_position between 1 and 3
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8637d/7/3)**:

```
| ORDINAL_POSITION |
|------------------|
|                1 |
|                2 |
|                3 |
```

Answer (score 12):

## USING UNION

Others have submitted answers trying aggregation to collect data without using `UNION`

- `May 12, 2014` : [Query improvements without UNION](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64977/query-improvements-without-union)
- `May 05, 2015` : [Calculating values from three related tables, without using join or union](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/100695/calculating-values-from-three-related-tables-without-using-join-or-union)
- `Feb 20, 2012` : [SQL Data aggregation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13454/sql-data-aggregation)

In this instance, what makes `UNION` an absolute must is the merging of three columns into a single column. Nothing could be more elegant that using `UNION`

```
SELECT her_name AS name FROM foo
UNION
SELECT his_name AS name FROM foo
UNION
SELECT other_name AS name FROM foo;
```

This would produce a distinct list of names.

If the intent is to select some columns and generate a single column list of the distinct values, then Dynamic SQL is needed to produce such a query. For this example, let's suppose the following

- `mydb` schema
- table called `foo`
- columns to select together

  - `her_name`
  - `his_name`
  - `other_name`

Here is the Dynamic SQL to generate the same query

```
USE mydb
SET group_concat_max_len = 1048576;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT('SELECT ',column_name,' AS name FROM ',table_name)
    SEPARATOR ' UNION ')
INTO @sql
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema=DATABASE() AND table_name='foo' AND column_name IN
('her_name','his_name','other_name');
SELECT @sql\G
PREPARE s FROM @sql;
EXECUTE s;
DEALLOCATE PREPEARE s;
```

The `SELECT @sql\G` will let you see the generated SQL

Without formally scripting a Stored Procedure, this is as good as it is going to get.

## WITHOUT USING UNION

If the goal is to strictly not to use `UNION`, you need a temp table with a `PRIMARY KEY`:

```
CREATE TABLE names SELECT her_name name FROM foo WHERE 1=2;
ALTER TABLE names ADD PRIMARY KEY (name);
INSERT IGNORE INTO names (name) SELECT her_name FROM foo;
INSERT IGNORE INTO names (name) SELECT his_name FROM foo;
INSERT IGNORE INTO names (name) SELECT other_name FROM foo;
SELECT * FROM names;
DROP TABLE names;
```

## LOOK MOM, NO UNION !!!

Answer (score 2):

A semi-solution:  They will be in *column*.  (But they are also in a single row, sort of.)

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS("\n", her_name, his_name, other_name) AS name FROM foo
```

For example:

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT_WS("\n", province) FROM Provinces;
+---------------------------+
| CONCAT_WS("\n", province) |
+---------------------------+
| Alberta                   |
| British Columbia          |
| Manitoba                  |
| New Brunswick             |
| Newfoundland and Labrador |
| Nova Scotia               |
...
```

If it is going to a web page, then consider `"<br>"` instead of `"\n"`.

Answer (score 1):

For MariaDB users: there are virtual sequence tables containing sequence of integers. No need to create temporary / auxiliary table with those integers!

Cross join (Cartesian product) on such table and use `ELT` to extract n-th column!

**Solution:**

```
SELECT ELT(seq_1_to_3.seq, foo.his_name, foo.her_name, foo.other_name) AS name
FROM foo
CROSS JOIN seq_1_to_3;
```

**Explanation:**

Virtual table `seq_1_to_3` has 1 column `seq` and contains 3 integers in that column: 1, 2, and 3.
In this query we go through each row in table `foo` 3 times (because of the cross-join with virtual table `seq_1_to_3`) and pick only one `seq`-th column from the given list of columns: `his_name`, `her_name`, `other_name`.