# Calculating values from three related tables, without using join or union

Tags: sql-server

I have a simple basic three tables on SQL Server database:
[image]

What is needed is to get the quantity available, **without using joins or unions** which is calculated:

> Quantity Available  = Items Opening Balance - Items Delivered +
>   Items Received

Any Ideas are welcome.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?  Just `join` up the tables, and presto, "voila".

Comment: You have a relationship between 3 tables. You cannot simply sum the quantities per table and add them together as that would merely reflect the total quantity available. What you are likely asking for is the quantity available *by item*

Comment: Someone has placed an unreasonable constraint upon you and your solution. Instead of using the correct tool for the job, a relational query, you must extract the data into some external tool, like Excel, or craft a specific program, C#/PowerShell/etc, to extract all the data from the tables and perform the "join" logic in there which is silly and inefficient

Comment: Is this for school or work? If for work, you should push back -- joins should be used when appropriate.

Comment: Not for school, or work, it is for seek of knowledge only.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems you are being asked to write the query using correlated subqueries, for example:

```
SELECT
    IOB.ItemID,
    IOB.Descript,
    IOB.Quantity +
    (
        -- Total received for this item
        SELECT ISNULL(SUM(IR.Quantity), 0)
        FROM dbo.ItemsReceived AS IR
        WHERE IR.ItemID = IOB.ItemID
    )
    -
    (
        -- Total delivered for this item
        SELECT TotalDelivered = ISNULL(SUM(ID.Quantity), 0)
        FROM dbo.ItemsDelivered AS ID
        WHERE ID.ItemID = IOB.ItemID
    )
FROM dbo.ItemsOpeningBalance AS IOB;
```

<kbd>[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f3dba/2)</kbd>

If you're using SQL Server 2005 or later, you could also use `APPLY` (a lateral or correlated join) but I suspect this would be viewed as not in the spirit of the exercise. The following actually requires SQL Server 2008 or later, because it (gratuitously) uses `GROUP BY ()`.

```
SELECT
    IOB.ItemID,
    IOB.Descript,
    QuantityAvailable =
        IOB.Quantity +
        ISNULL(ItemsReceived.Quantity, 0) -
        ISNULL(ItemsDelivered.Quantity, 0)
FROM dbo.ItemsOpeningBalance AS IOB
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT SUM(IR.Quantity)
    FROM dbo.ItemsReceived AS IR
    WHERE IR.ItemID = IOB.ItemID
    GROUP BY ()
) AS ItemsReceived (Quantity)
OUTER APPLY 
(
    SELECT SUM(ID.Quantity)
    FROM dbo.ItemsDelivered AS ID
    WHERE ID.ItemID = IOB.ItemID
    GROUP BY ()
) AS ItemsDelivered (Quantity);
```

<kbd>[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f3dba/4)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

A similar but different and much poorer approach to Paul's would be to compute the value as scalars and then do your calculation.

```
DECLARE
    @QuantityOpening int
,   @QuantityDelivered int
,   @QuantityReceived int
,   @ItemID int = 1;

WITH ItemsOpeningBalance(ItemID, Quantity) AS
(
    SELECT
    *
    FROM
    (
        VALUES
            (1, 10)
        ,   (2, 20)
    ) D(a,b)
)
,   ItemsDelivered(SalesOrderID, ItemID, Quantity) AS
(
    SELECT
    *
    FROM
    (
    VALUES
        (100, 1, 2)
    ,   (1000, 1, 3)
    ,   (200, 2, 100)
    ) D(a,b,c)
)
,   ItemsReceived(PurchaseOrderID, ItemID, Quantity) AS
(
    SELECT
    *
    FROM
    (
    VALUES
        (10000, 1, 5)
    ,   (20000, 2, 100)
    ) D(a,b,c)
)
-- Watch this pattern
SELECT
    @QuantityOpening = COALESCE(
(
    SELECT 
        SUM(IOB.Quantity) AS StartingQuantity
    FROM
        ItemsOpeningBalance AS IOB
    WHERE
        IOB.ItemID = @ItemID
),  0)
,  @QuantityDelivered = COALESCE(
(
    SELECT 
        SUM(ID.Quantity) AS StartingQuantity
    FROM
        ItemsDelivered AS ID
    WHERE
        ID.ItemID = @ItemID
), 0)
,@QuantityReceived = COALESCE(
(
    SELECT 
        SUM(IR.Quantity) AS StartingQuantity
    FROM
        ItemsReceived AS IR
    WHERE
        IR.ItemID = @ItemID
), 0);

SELECT
    @QuantityOpening - @QuantityDelivered +  @QuantityReceived AS TotalAmount;
```

Comment: Dear Billin thank you for your answer, your are specifically retrieving and calculating and for item 1 only, while Patrick approach more simpler and calculates for all items in all tables.